# What's the right way to wait for ng-init values to be set?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-timeout

I have an "**ng-init**" directive in my HTML that initializes the value of "**data.id**" in my Angular.js data model. Let's say for now that I can't change how this works.

Now, I want to make an HTTP request as soon as my page loads, where the URL will depend on this data.id value. So far, the following seems to work:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  "use strict";

  $scope.data = {};

  $timeout(function () {
    $http.get("/api/Something?id=" + $scope.data.id);
  }, 0);
});
```

However, using a timer with a timeout of zero seems clunky. (And if I omit the $timeout code and simply call $http.get directly, then $scope.data.id is, of course, undefined).

Is there a better way to wait until ng-init has executed before issuing the $http request? And is the timeout-based code above guaranteed to work in all cases / on all browsers, etc?

Comment: i would suggest your model or controller looking after the data and the view just reflecting the data, not setting it.  that is a much more "angular" approach imho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use a watch

```
$scope.$watch('data.id',function(newValue,oldValue) {
  if(newValue) {
    $http.get("/api/Something?id=" + $scope.data.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work and I've accepted the answer. I'm curious though whether there's an answer to the 2nd part of my question (if I kept the $timeout code, is it guaranteed to work or does it just happen to work?)

Comment: Have a look at this discussion on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful#comment14183689_779785. Hope it helps you :) It may not work if there is a substantial delay.

Comment: but this thing will fire each time the data.id changes, not only on fist init, isn't it?